# What was Tripp thinking?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In S02E10 of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*,

> Coulson went into tunnel to save Skye and to satisfy his curiosity despite he knew about bomb they implanted. Knowing that, Trip jumped into the tunnel without protective suit to disarm all bombs to save Coulson and Skye.

It could turn out to be an extinction level event for Mankind. What was Tripp thinking? Was saving few lives necessary over survival of human race or Earth?

Comment: According to the tv/movie industry, saving even 1 life is good enough to risk the extinction of the human race (greater good). In so many movies and tv shows, the good guys are always the ones that tries to save a few.

Comment: Yeah - now ask Tripp how that worked out for him. Oh, wait...

Answer (score 3):

As has been said, he is probably making the wrong call, and it results in his death.  At the time he was weighing a possible extinction level event (that they didn't have clear evidence of) vs the life of his commanding officer and another agent.